# Assign values to a Model from another at OnGetAsync in Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I am trying assign values to a `Model` from another at `OnGetAsync` in `Razor Page` for some data validation and assign them back to actual `Model` on `OnPostAsync` for data saving.

I get `NullReferenceException` error at this line `Input.TestName = TestData.TestName;`

```
public class TestData
{
    [Key]
    public int TestID { get; set; }
    public string TestName { get; set; }
}
```

Page Model

```
    private readonly Test.Models.TestContext _context;
    public EditModel(Test.Models.TestContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public TestData TestData { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required, MaxLength(50), MinLength(3)]
        public string TestName { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        TestData = await _context.TestData.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.TestID == id);
        Input.TestName = TestData.TestName; //Error Occurs here. TestData.TestName has value while debug.
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        TestData.TestName = Input.TestName;
        _context.Attach(TestData).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

I tried `TestName` outside of `InputModel class` which is working well but I have plenty of properties to use like this. so I wanted to put them under one `class`

Please suggest what I am missing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've confirmed in your question that `TestData.TestName` has a value when viewed in the debugger, you should turn your attention to `Input.TestName`. More specifically, this likely means that the `Input` property itself is `null`, which would result in your `NullReferenceException`.

This makes sense, too. When `OnPostAsync` is called, ASP.NET Core attempts to bind to your `Input` property using data from the request, which results in it creating an instance of `InputModel` for you. This is enabled with the use of the `[BindProperty]` attribute you have in place on the `Input` property itself.

However, when `OnGetAsync` is called, the same process does not occur. By default, `[BindProperty]` will only trigger non-GET requests to perform this binding, which means `Input` inside of your `OnGetAsync` call will be `null` (this is the default for reference-type properties).

To fix the issue, update your `OnGetAsync` implementation to create its own instance of `Input` before attempting to set its `TestName` value. Here's one way to achieve that:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
    TestData = await _context.TestData.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.TestID == id);
    Input = new InputModel { TestName = TestData.TestName };
    return Page();
}
```

It's also worth remembering that your call to `FirstOrDefaultAsync` is going to set `TestData` to `null` if the id doesn't match, which wil give you a different `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: TestData is being assigned by await... Is there a default reason for not getting NullReferrence error.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand that previous comment. Did you try the code example I provided?

Comment: Yes, it's working Kirk, previous comment is when TestData is assigned without an instance, why not Input.